# IntelliJ warning "cannot resolve variable" on JSTL

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller, intellij-idea, jstl, warnings

I am writing a web-server using Tomcat.
The tech i decided to use is JSTL.

I want to first say that it works, **the page displays successfully and everything runs**.
I do like to get rid of warnings.
The warning i get from intelliJ is: "Cannot resolve variable ''", it comes from a JSP page where i have some JSTL code. The jsp page is called from my controller using RequestDispatcher forward function.

```
request.setAttribute("resultsModel", resultsModel);
request.setAttribute("times", times);
request.setAttribute("emailErr", emailErr);
request.setAttribute("qid", id);
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("ShowResults.jsp");
view.forward(request, respone);
```

The JSP page then uses this variables in a variety of JSTL tags, example from page:

```
<c:choose>
<%-- When database access was succesfull --%>
<c:when test="${resultsModel != null}">
    <c:choose>
        <%-- When the job ID exists --%>
        <c:when test="${resultsModel.jobEntity != null}">
```

ect...

The warning is then given on those positions where i try to access resultModel.
I tried adding a jsp:useBean tag as such:

```
<jsp:useBean id="resultsModel" scope="request" type="bgu.bioinf.rnaSequenceSniffer.Model.ResultsModel"/>
```

But I still get a warning.
Any idea? Something i am doing really wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: You can press Alt-Enter to select a QuickFix, did you tried this?

Comment: If everything works fine, then leave it as it is. Don't pollute your code with useless code just to make your IDE happy. It tries to figure out possible mistakes, and fails at doing so. Accept it. You're smarter than the IDE.

Comment: QuickFix has nothing on it. I am ignoring it ATM, it just that my last boss really imprinted in me the need to compile with 0 warning, they might hide some real error some times.

Comment: Try to find an answer before ask the question... Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694392/intellij-not-resolving-el-variables-within-jsp-code-inspection-or-autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

I meet this question too, and really bother me.
Today I googled this problem and find no solution.
However I used the `ModelMap`  rather than `HttpServletRequest`.

```
map.put("info",info);
```

And no doubt I got this warning,then I changed the method:

```
map.addAttribute("info",info);
```

I want to say this way does solve the warning,you can even `ctrl` + `button1` to navigate the bean in the controller.
I don't know if this solve the problem in other scenario,But in intellij 2018.1 I just get rid of it.Hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project Structure | Libaraies | Add | From Maven` search `javax.servlet:jstl`, then select `javax.servlet:jstl:1.2`.

My version is latest.